# Get Distance in Custom Script in Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am currently working on creating a custom script in Java for Elasticsearch to assist with scoring. If I was using mvel I could just say

```
doc['field_name'].distance(lat, lon)
```

In java there seems to be no (seemingly available) distance functions that I can run against a field in the document. This is ok, I guess, because I could use the Haversine distance formula if I had it. However, if there was something built into the Elasticsearch libraries then I would rather use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translated to the native script, your mvel statement would look like this:

```
((GeoPointDocFieldData)doc().field("field_name")).distance(lat, lon)
```

It's also possible to retrieve lists of latitudes and longitudes as arrays using `getLats()` and `getLons()` method and calculate the distances using

```
GeoDistance.PLANE.calculate(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit)
```

Comment: and would the field be an array of lat,lon?